# Best practises for opening and closing SQLite connection

Tags: sql, sqlite, mobile

Which of the two approaches should be taken when opening and closing SQLite connections on an embedded device.

Approach A:
- Open the connection once at the start of the application and close the connection when the application exits

Approach B:
- Open the connection each time a SQLite query must be executed and close the connection once it has finished

Answer (score 0):

I would go with approach B. This way you are avoiding potential locks and multiple processes/connections trying to perform write operations on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Reopening the connection requires that SQLite reopens the file again and that it re-parses the database schema again.

SQLite automatically handles locks to prevent multiple connections from writing at the same time, and keeps these locks only while a transaction is active.
(See [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html).)

Approach B makes all database accesses more inefficient, and has no upside.
It would make sense only if it happened to make your own code simpler.